# How to tell rpm to look into specific directory for dependencies?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, rpm, suse

I have an rpm package that needs to be installed on SLES 11. The installtion fails due to unresolved dependecies.

```
$ rpm -ivh xpra-0.3.11-1.x86_64.rpm
warning: xpra-0.3.11-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID f18ad6bb
error: Failed dependencies:
        libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by xpra-0.3.11-1.x86_64
        python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by xpra-0.3.11-1.x86_64
```

When checked, default python installation on SLES 11 was 2.6. I couldn't find python 2.7 rpm package for SLES 11. I have installed python 2.7 by building the source.

Now, whenever I try to install the same software, I am the getting same errors.

How to tell rpm package manager to look into specific directory to find the required dependencies??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - the only dependencies `rpm` can ever know about are ones which were installed using `rpm`.

Comment: Thanks! I will see if I can build python 2.7 rpm package for SLES. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may download a pre-built python 2.7 RPM from this [site](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=python&srodzaj=3) and install it with e.g `python-rpm -i 2.7.3-3.6.1.x86_64.rpm`. Bear in mind that I'm not a SLES user, so my suggestion is a kind of a shot in the dark.